# Styling only one element in an array, in Leaflet's pointToLayer

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, leaflet

I'm trying to only style one element in an array and apply it to `pointToLayer`, while the other elements in the array stay at a default parameter. Specifically, I'm trying to have the most recent earthquake point to have a radius weight of 3 while leaving the remainder earthquake points with a radius weight of 1.

Here is a picture of my legend/points on the map. As you can see Recent is identified with a larger radius weight.

[image]

I thought the best way to do this was to create a function and call it within `pointToLayer` under the `weight` attribute. My thought process to create such a function is as follows.

1. Loop through the geojson which identifies the time, `feature.properties.time`, and place the times in an array.
2. Create an `if` statement that sees if the first element in the array is larger (most current date) and make its weight 3 while leaving the weight of the remaining elements 1.

I'm having trouble comprehending how I should structure the if statement since I only want one element of the array to have a different style then the remaining elements.

Here is the code, any help would be appreciated. The function I'm working on is called `mostRecent`. Thank you.

```
// most recent earthquake identifer
function mostRecent(time) {
    var dates=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < time.length; i++) {
        dates.push(time[i])
    }
    if (dates[0] > dates[1]) {
        weight = 3
    } else {      
        weight = 1
    }
return weight
}

// adds geojson feed of earthquakes from USGS url (must create a function to layer it on leaflet)
$.getJSON('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.geojson', function(earthQuakes) {
    var points = L.geoJSON(earthQuakes, {
        filter: eqFilter,
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {  // binds data in geosjon to a popup
            var eqDate = new Date(feature.properties.time); // converts epoch date
            layer.bindPopup(
                '<b>Location: </b>' + feature.properties.place + '<br>' +
                '<b>Magnitude: </b>' + feature.properties.mag + '<br>' +
                '<b>Depth: </b>' + feature.geometry.coordinates[2] + 'km' + '<br>' +
                '<b>Time: </b>' + eqDate.toGMTString() + '<br>' +
                '<br><center><a href=' + feature.properties.url + '>USGS Details</a></center>',
            )
        },
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng){  // changes default icons to cicrles and styles accordingly
            return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
                radius: circleSize(feature.properties.mag),
                fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.mag),
                color: "#000",
                weight: mostRecent(feature.properties.time),
                opacity: 1,
                fillOpacity: 0.5,
            });

        }
    }).addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(points.getBounds()); // pans to points
});
```