# How to style one array element, different from the rest, in leafelt?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, leaflet

I'm trying to only style one element in an array but I'm uncertain how to write the if statement. I'd like to achieve `dates[0]` returns a weight of `3` while the remaining elements in the array return a weight of `1`. Is this possible?

**Function:**

```
var dates=[]
function mostRecent(time) {
    dates.push(time)
    if (dates[0]){
        weight = 3
    } else {
        weight = 1
    }
return weight
}
```

**Style:**

```
 pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng){  // changes default icons to circles and styles accordingly
            return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
                radius: circleSize(feature.properties.mag),
                fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.mag),
                color: "#000",
                weight: mostRecent(feature.properties.time),
                opacity: 1,
                fillOpacity: 0.5,
            });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling only one element in an array, in Leaflet's pointToLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59039158/styling-only-one-element-in-an-array-in-leaflets-pointtolayer)

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
var i = 0;

pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng){
    if(i === 0){
      return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
          radius: circleSize(feature.properties.mag),
          fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.mag),
          color: "#000",
          weight: 3,
          opacity: 1,
          fillOpacity: 0.5,
        }
      );
    }else{
      return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
          radius: circleSize(feature.properties.mag),
          fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.mag),
          color: "#000",
          weight: 1,
          opacity: 1,
          fillOpacity: 0.5,
        }
      );
    }
    i++;

  });
```